# In Docker for Windows no option for shared drives?

Tags: docker-for-windows

I am using Docker in Windows 10. It is running with Windows container.

For my .met application I am creating docker image and running it in my PC.

In my application I am reading many files from one folder for that I am providing path. But when I am debugging it with Docker at that time it is not accepting that path.

How can I share that folder with Docker ?

For Windows container there is no option for shared drive.

Like this....
[windows container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SXha.png)

For Linux container it is available.
Like here...
[Linux container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DVsC.png)

Comment: My impression is that because Windows containers run “natively”, there is no need for extra steps. Just use the `-v` option as you would on Linux.

Comment: I tried using -v but it's not working. can you give me any example ? so I can try again. Can you specify where should I put mypath and where container path ?